# Como poner una foto por defecto con php(subiendo a la base de datos con longblob)?

Tags: php, vanilla

Queria ver como poder resolver esta incognita , debido a que ya he probado distintos metodos pero la base de datos me tira error , el codigo que urilizo es este

```
if(!isset($_FILES['Foto'])){
  $foto= '../../img/foto por defecto.jpg';
}else{
/*\
(esta es la linea32)*/$foto=addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Foto']['tmp_name']));
}
```

y en el formulario

```
   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
           
            <input type="text" name="Producto"  class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" name="Descripcion"  class="form-control" placeholder="Descripcion del producto" required>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="text" name="Marca" class="form-control" placeholder="Marca" required>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <br>
           <input type="number" name="Precio"  placeholder="Precio del producto" required>
           
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <br>
           <input type="number" name="Cantidad"  placeholder="Cantidad del producto" required>
           
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <br>
           <input type="file" name="Foto"  placeholder="Insertar imagen del producto" required >
           
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" name="agregar" value="agregar" class="btn btn-success " >
        </div>
        </form>
```

El error es:
Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Facultad\Global_lab3\Inventory\administrador\insertar.php:32 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Facultad\Global_lab3\Inventory\administrador\insertar.php(32): file_get_contents('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Facultad\Global_lab3\Inventory\administrador\insertar.php on line 32

Comment: "la base de datos me tira error", qué error? Por lo que describes, el lío no es mostrar la foto por defecto sino algo con la base de datos (que desconocemos). Por favor, ve a [edit] la pregunta y añade la información faltante (comenzando por el mensaje de error completo)

Comment: Además de lo dicho por Alfabravo... ¿Por qué quieres algo por defecto si también declaras la imagen como `required`?

Comment: podrías mostrar la estructura completa de tu formulario ?

Comment: ahora lo agrego, el required lo habia puesto para que no saliera el error de mysql

Comment: deberia verificar la funcion file_get_contents, estoy viendo la documentación oficial (nunca he usado esa funcion) pero por lo visto te faltan parametros o no lo estas ejecutando para lo que necesitas

Comment: No , al subir la imagen funciona , el tema es cuando no subo imagen